# Redirect Multiple Domains to Subfolders and Hide the subfolder from URL

Tags: .htaccess, domain

I have sat up two virtual host on the same ip and same document root with Apache, because I want to use shared files and contents in the document root.

I want my second website point to a subfolder of the document root

```
http://example.com Loads http://example.com/subfolder
```

I tried various rewrite rules in the .htaccess they all can redirect but maintain the subfolder in the url which I dont like I mean the url would be

```
 http://example.com/subfolder
```

while I want

```
 http://example.com
```

these are what I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$   
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://example.com/subfolder
```

OR

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

the second one also gives a 500 Internal Server Error, what should i do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want to do is not make a redirect but to rewrite the query with RewriteRule. So it should be like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example1.com$   
RewriteRule !^subfolder1/ subfolder1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example2.com$   
RewriteRule !^subfolder2/ subfolder2%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

F.ex. the query http://www.example1.com/foo.html will be treated by Apache like it was a query http://www.example1.com/subfolder1/foo.html. Change the domain in this query and the file will be served from subfolder2.

While testing my solution I found also this, quite similar to your problem:
[Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611506/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable-configuratio)

Comment: just a little problem, it rewrites every file to subfolder2, what if I just want to rewrite php files and use for example the javascript and css files from the document root (the parent)

Comment: thank you it seems I find the solution to exclude some files by RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$ [NC]

Answer (score 1):

The term "Redirect" means that your server tells the browser to go fetch another page instead of the one it asked for. When the browser does that, it will also update the path in the Location bar.

In order to hide the new location, you need to instead use [mod_rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever). That is a module that will look at what the server asks for and translate it to a different place on the server, without issuing a redirect.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for mistyping the second try. I modified my question, actually I also tried Rewrite but they also doesnt work

Comment: Turn on rewrite logging and add the logs to the question

Answer (score 0):

How would i make these ssl? I'm using this...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainone.com$
RewriteRule ^(?!domainone/)(.*)$ /domainone/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domaintwo.com$
RewriteRule ^(?!domaintwo/)(.*)$ /domaintwo/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domainthree.com$
RewriteRule ^(?!domainthree/)(.*)$ /domainthree/$1
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/521069)